# Dwarf Fortress labor preferences

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I find out what dwarves, if any, have a given job active in their labor preferences so I can either remove other preferences that are taking up their time or change another dwarf's preferences?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tzenes [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/dwarf-fortress-labor-preferences/1604#1604) is strictly correct.  There is however no way in the game to see a list of all dwarves with a specific labor enabled (ie: mining).  You must iterate through all your dwarves to check.

However, a custom utility called Dwarf Therapist has been written to allow you to do exactly what you want to do.

- [Dwarf Therapist Forum/Info Page](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=39229.0)
- [Dwarf Therapist Project/Download Page](http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist)

Comment: I must say that is an amazing little app. I don't even assign preferences in game anymore.

Comment: IMHO, Dwarf Fortress is unplayable without Therapist. :)

Comment: I don't use it to assign preferences so much, but just checking who you've got and what they're capable of at a glance is great.

Comment: @C.Ross is there a mac version? or a generic unix version?

Comment: @Mechko, Unfortunately I believe it is Windows only at the moment.

Comment: There is a Mac Version that was ported by someone else here - http://code.google.com/r/jofarrell-dwarftherapistosx/ But it seems to be inactive so whether it still works with the latest version is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the dwarf, either through 'v' or 'c' and then choosing a dwarf.
2. Select preferences ('p')
3. Select labors ('l')
4. Select the category of labor you want to change.

Its worth noting that currently selected labors will be highlighted, as will their categories.

Comment: "Select the category of labor you want to change."
I can't browse through the categories, though. WHen I press up or down, the cursor moves on the map. No other key seems to work for that, either. How can I do it?

Comment: @Marcin it should be `+` or `-` to navigate this menu, unless you've changed your key bindings